# Procedure that for looks for an id in different table and inserts it if there is no entry for that id

Tags: php, mysql, procedure, routines

I need to write a procedure in mysql that runs every night and performs the following:-

For each 'id' from 'associate' table find if there is an entry in 'status table' for a particular 'department' . If there is an entry then move on to next 'id' else insert a row in status table for that id.

**Associate Table**

Assoc_Id

Assoc_Project

Assoc_Assigned_On

**Status Table**

Sub_id

Assoc_Id

Sub_on

Department

I just have no clue about how to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please at least provide relevant table structures ?

Comment: "Move on to next id."  With respect, you're thinking procedurally when trying to figure out how to do something with a declarative language. Don't think "for-each", think about sets of values, and you'll have an easier time with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided a full schema, I'm unsure of primary/foreign keys on the tables, but here is a query that can help you:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_status (Assoc_Id, Sub_on, Department)
SELECT a.Assoc_Id, [Your Sub_on Value], 'IT'
FROM tbl_associate a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_status s ON a.Assoc_Id = s.Assoc_Id AND s.Department = 'IT'
WHERE s.Sub_Id IS NULL;
```

The basic idea here is to `LEFT JOIN` on the `status` table from the `associate` table where the `Assoc_Id`'s are equal and the department value is the one you're searching for.  The `WHERE` clause filters the results so that it only shows records that are not currently in the `status` table based on the join condition.  I chose `Sub_Id` because I assumed that is the primary key.  It doesn't really matter what you choose here except that the value has to be a non-null field in the `status` table order for this query to work.

Comment: Here is the detail about primary key & foreign key.  **Associate Table**  Assoc_Id (Primary Key)  Assoc_Project  Assoc_Assigned_On  **Status Table**  Sub_id (Primary Key)  Assoc_Id (Foreign Key)  Sub_on Department    What I want my procedure to do is to take each AssociateId from Associate table and insert a row in tbl_status ONLY if there is **no entry** for that AssociateId for a particular department (say IT).  Example:If there are 2 Associates ABC1 & ABC2. ABC1 has an entry for dept IT in tbl_stat. Then what I want is that, a row should be inserted for ABC2 in tbl_stat.

Comment: Okay I edited my answer slightly so this query will work for department `IT`.  The only other thing you would need to specify is the value for `Sub_on` in the `SELECT` statement, since I'm not sure what kind of field it is.  Otherwise, this query should be exactly what you are looking for.